# Typo3 LanguageMenu Error "sr_language_menu_pi1" no rendering definition

Tags: content-management-system, typo3

Shortly, i needed to help a good friend, to move her complete typo3 install to another provider.

There was no chance in getting help from the developer at all.

- I exported and imported the tables
- downloaded all of the folder and uploaded it again
- I set new InstallTool Password and added new Administrator
- I updated the MySQL-Connection

Now everything seems to work correctly, BESIDES an error calling at the top of the page (where the language selection is supposed to be) saying:

> ERROR: Content Element type "sr_language_menu_pi1" has no rendering definition!

For now, I tried to hide this annoying layer with CSS-property display none ;)

But it's a website where I need to have multiple languages enabled.

I have no experience with typo3, so please describe possible solutions as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens e.g. under TYPO3 6.2.17.

You must have a sysfolder called "Templates" where you create a new extension template setup for the extension sr_language_menu. (Template Module)
Use the title "+ext sr_language_menu".
There you enter a constants part like this:

```
plugin.tx_srlanguagemenu {

    addSelectionListHeader = 0
    showCurrentFirst = 0
    defaultLanguageISOCode = DE
    hideIfNoAltLanguages = 1
    showInactive = 0
    pointerImage = 
    defaultLayout = 0
    addLinksListHeader = 0
    doNotLinkCurrent = 1
    separator = 
    token = |
    selectionListSeparator =
    showCurrent = 1
    useIsoLanguageCountryCode = 1

}
```

And you enter a setup like this.

```
plugin.tx_srlanguagemenu {

    _CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE >
    flags.stdWrap.split.wrap = <ul id="langmenu">|*| | |*| |</ul>
    flag.NO.stdWrap.wrap = <li>|</li>
    flag.INACT.stdWrap.wrap = <li>|</li>
    flag.CUR.stdWrap.wrap = <li>|</li>
    links.stdWrap.split.wrap >
}
```

Then go to the tab "Include static (from extensions):" and set the
Selected Items to 
**"Language Menu setup (sr_language_menu)" and
"Language Menu CSS Styles (sr_language_menu)"**

Then go to your main template setup. (Template Module).
Edit Template "Main Template" on page "..."
Go to the tab "Includes" and add the "+ext sr_language_menu". to "Include Basis Template:". You can use the page browser in the new popup window to navigate to the Templates folder and select the record with the template name "+ext sr_language_menu".

Then you must install static_info_tables 6.2.1 or higher, and install the country specific static_info_tables extensions. Deinstall sr_language_menu and reinstall it again. Then open the Extension Manager an see the green round arrow symbol "Execute the update script". 
Afterwards the error message has gone and the language menu shows up.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if the templates of this extension is present on the project installation.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you din not include static from template of "sr_language_menu"

- Go to Web > Template > Root page
- Info/Modify: edit whole template
- Something like: http://screencast.com/t/jq3rggQy

cheers,
Ghanshyam